# How to change property of a tag in html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have:

```
<a id="save-button" href="data:application/xml;charset=utf-8,your code here" download="test.cod">Save</a>
```

I can change the href property with:

```
element.href = "what I want";
```

but when I do

```
element.download = "what I want";
```

it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can change the download property?

Thanks

Comment: try element.setAttribute("download", "what I want")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `download` property is not supported widely which is still an experimental API.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement)

---

Use [`Element#setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method to update an attribute.

```
element.setAttribute('download', "what I want");
```